# Unity: Disabling/Enabling GameObjects and increasing index of an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, indexing

I have an array of gameobjects, and want to activate one with index 0, and after a tap of a button, the gameobject with index 0 gets hidden, and the one with index 1 gets active and so on.

```
public GameObject[] QuestionList;
private int QuestionsArrayIndex;

public void Start()
    {
        QuestionsArrayIndex = 0;
        QuestionList[QuestionsArrayIndex].SetActive(true);
        Shuffle();
    }

public void ScreenTap()
{
    if (QuestionList[QuestionsArrayIndex].activeInHierarchy)
    {
        QuestionsArrayIndex++;
        QuestionList[QuestionsArrayIndex].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you encountering a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void ScreenTap()
    {
        if (QuestionList[QuestionsArrayIndex].activeInHierarchy && QuestionsArrayIndex < QuestionList.Length)
        {
            QuestionList[QuestionsArrayIndex].SetActive(false);
            QuestionsArrayIndex++;
            QuestionList[QuestionsArrayIndex].SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

This might be the way you want to do. Also you need to check for index otherwise you might encounter the IndexOutOfBounds Exception.